# WPF WebBrowser: changing IE print dialog properties programmatically

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, internet-explorer, printing

I'm writing application with WPF `WebBrowser` control. It's source is result of xml/xslt sourse from database.

In the window that contains `WebBrowser` there is button for printing with handler:

```
mshtml.IHTMLDocument2 doc = WBrowser.Document as mshtml.IHTMLDocument2;
doc.execCommand("Print", true, 0);
```

but in this case there is no background in printed document. I've researched this issue, and it's trouble with property in Internet Explorer page setup dialog - Allow the printing of background colors and images.

I've tried to change this by this code:

```
RegistryKey regKey = Registry.CurrentUser
        .OpenSubKey("Software", true)
        .OpenSubKey("Microsoft", true)
        .OpenSubKey("Internet Explorer", true)
        .OpenSubKey("PageSetup", true);

var defaultValue = regKey.GetValue("Print_Background");
regKey.SetValue("Print_Background", "yes");
```

but this is bad code. I don't want to change registry values for one simple bool parameter.

So, my question is: how can I change this parameter programmatically via code-behind without registry modification?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only way to modify the print settings without modifying the registry is via [Print Templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753280.aspx) and it seems like no one has really used them from the .NET web browser control.

However, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19172580/548304) has additional resources regarding print templates and their usage from C++/win32.

If you're open to using ActiveX for printing the page, you could use the `SHDocVw.WebBrowser` which then gives you access to the ability to specify the print template, as noted in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6063048/548304)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this without the registry modification.